# Reverse a vector without rev()

Tags: r, sequence

We have to reverse it without rev(). Not allowed to use if/for loops. It has to work for numeric(0) as well.

```
v[length(v):1]
```

Does not output correctly for vectors with length 0.

Comment: Try `v[length(v):min(length(v), 1)]` (assuming `min` can be used)

Comment: `v[length(v):1]` returns NULL for `c()`. Correct in my books.

Comment: @akrun what is the 1 for in your code? Thanks btw

Comment: What output would you expect if you have a vector with length 0? Why would you even try to reverse a vector which doesn't contain any values?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CharlestonChen the reason I used `min(length(v), 1)` is for special cases `v <- numeric(0)` where length(v) is 0, thus `min(length(v), 1)#
[1] 0` and `length(v):min(length(v), 1)#
[1] 0` instead of `0:1`, thus returning `v[length(v):min(length(v), 1)]#
numeric(0)` which also works for length > 0 i.e. `v <- c(4, 5)#
> v[length(v):min(length(v), 1)]#
[1] 5 4`

Comment: @Maria-ChristinaWeber In this case, this strikes me as a little puzzle or exercise to learn how R handles special cases. But more generally, it's good to know of exceptions if this is part of a custom function, and one a day the function's user feeds in a length-0 vector.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `switch`, and it requires only a single calculation of the length.

```
v <- numeric(0L)  ## creating vector of length zero

v[{len <- length(v); switch((len > 0L) + 1L, 0L, len:1)}]
# numeric(0)
```

Comment: @akrun True. Maybe a switch is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
> v <- numeric(0)

> v[length(v) - seq_along(v) + 1]
numeric(0)
```

and

```
> v <- c(5, 2, 7, 8, 3)

> v[length(v) - seq_along(v) + 1]
[1] 3 8 7 2 5
```